# Why may tensions calculated in different ways be slightly different?

Tags: classical-mechanics

An question I am doing gives this situation:
[image]

Mass1 is 4kg. And mass2 is 7kg.

I expect the tension to be the same, no matter which mass I use in the calculation. But...

a=5.17

T1=7(9.81-5.17)=32.48N   (which is not the same as T2=0.3*9.81*4+5.17*4=32.452N

I use the same number for gravitational acceleration, why other reason may there be for which the tensions turns out not to be the same?

Comment: Who says a = 5.17 m/s^2? You've got two expressions for the tension T1 and T2, that are supposed to yield the same value. So, you should solve for the acceleration a by equating the two expressions.

Comment: @CountIblis, I did...(m1a)(Ff)=m2g-m2a.  Ff is applied to m1

Answer (score 1):

The two objects are connected by a string, and should therefore have the same acceleration. Based on some of the equations you are showing, I believe that object 1 is subject to friction with a coefficient of 0.3. We can then write the equations for the forces:

$$F_1 = T - m_1 g \mu\\
F_2 = m_2 g - T\\
a_1 = \frac{F_1}{m_1}\\
a_2=\frac{F_2}{m_2}\\
a_1=a_2$$

These should all be consistent, as you said. We have five equations; we can work out the acceleration as follows:

$$\frac{F_2}{m_2} = \frac{F_1}{m_1}\\
g - \frac{T}{m_2} = \frac{T}{m_1} - g\mu\\
T = \frac{gm_1 m_2(1+\mu)}{m_1+m_2}$$

Substituting the values, we get $T = \frac{9.81*4*7*1.3}{11}=32.46 \rm{N}$

You can use the same equations to solve for the acceleration, which becomes

$$a = \frac{T-m_2 g}{m_2} = \frac{g m_1 (1+\mu)}{m_1+m_2}-g = -5.173 \rm{m/s^2}$$

Since these come from the same set of equations, these give consistent answers. The only reason you are getting slightly different answers is because you are trying to compare numbers to 4 significant figures when the intermediate result is given to only 3.

Rounding errors can creep in once you go from symbols to numbers. Keep your calculation symbolic as long as possible, and you will see that the error goes away. Or you discover the problem with your math...

Comment: Can it be said that the string exert a force on the sphere? If the sphere is pulling the prism, does the prism "pull back"?

Comment: Yes of course - this is just Newton's third law.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, you haven't broken physics. Instead, it was just a very slight rounding error. Your textbook gives you values *rounded* to 3 significant figures. Hence for an accurate result, you should round your answer to 3 significant figures, which in both cases gives 32.5N. I hope this answered your question.

Comment: I calculated a....

Comment: I am not clear which value you refer to.